# TFS 2015 Global Collection Settings Log?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Does anyone have an easy way to see who made a change to a TFS Collection's Global Settings?

Comment: To who ever down votes.  You could at least left a comment on why you felt to down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the information from **Activity Log**.

To see the Activity log, just go to `http://<yourserver>/tfs/_oi` if you have admin privileges.

You can filter the activities if you know the certain identities.

You can reference below screenshot, I changed the security setting in collection level, then can find the specific activity accordingly in the log.

[image]

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for.